# Tabulating a Joint Distribution Table in Octave

Tags: octave, distribution, dynamically-generated

We have the following data set ‘`DS`’ with observations for `A (a0, a1)` and `B (b1, b2, b3)`.

[image]

I use the following code to tabulate the joint probabilities associated with each unique row vector.

```
DS ( 1 , : ) =  [ ];
format short g
[U, ~, c] = unique ( DS ( : , : ), 'rows');
occ = accumarray ( c , 1 );
U2 = horzcat ( U, occ );
U3 = ( U2 ( : , 6 ) / sum ( U2 ( : , 6 ) ) );
Ujp = horzcat ( U2, U3 );
```

This provides `Ujp`:

[image: Ujp]

However, `Ujp` is not a fully parameterized table since it is missing possible pairs `(a0, b2)`, `(a1, b1)` and `(a1, b3)` – each of which have zero probability in this example.

So, I either need to:

***(a)*** develop a fully parameterized table (which is my original question).
or
***(b)*** be able to tell when a parameter such as `(a0, b2)` is missing from `Ujp`.

If I take the approach outlined in *(b)*, I can use:

```
a0b2 = [ 1  0  0  1  0];  
[ ~, index] = ismember ( a0b2, U, ‘rows’)   # which will return index = 0 since it’s missing in U
```

However, I’m currently at a loss as to how to code *(a)* which will provide a fully parameterized table including the parameters with zero probability – which will make answering certain questions regarding conditional probabilities much easier.

I'm new to Octave and am at a loss after a fair amount of searching. I would greatly appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Homework, right? You should add your code what you've already done so far

Comment: Not HW actually.  I have updated the post to add more color on the origin of the question.  Thanks for helping to point me in the right direction.